# Accessing xaml elements from code if I have their string name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a code in wich i need to be able to access to a different amount of prebuilt grids in XAMl and make them visible or collapsed

All grid are named like grid1,grid2,grid3 etc. I have the ability in code to obtain the string name via a random number and get the name od the grid i'd like to show.

I searched online and people suggest to use the reflect method, but i'm having a hard time trying to figure out the syntax that i have to use.

Best regards

Comment: And what is your exact problem?

Comment: Are you using a MVVM Framework?

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way of doing this is to just declare a `Name` value for each `Grid`...:

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
    ...
</Grid>
```

... and then you can access them by that name from the code behind:

```
Grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

However, this is WPF and that is generally not recommended. A preferred method would be to add some `bool` properties to your code behind or view model...:

```
public bool IsGrid1Visible { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface
```

... and then to bind these directly to the `Grid1.Visibility` property using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

```
<Grid Grid1.Visibility="{Binding IsGrid1Visible, Converter={StaticResource 
    BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    ...
</Grid>
```

Then you can change the `Grid.Visibility` value by simply setting the `IsGrid1Visible` property to `true` or `false`.